# Return Statements in Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

So I have a fairly decent understanding of the concept of recursion, but some implementations really trip me up. Take for instance this simple fibonacci function:

```
def fib(x):
    if x == 0 or x == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
```

I get that this breaks up the fibonacci calculation into smaller more manageable chunks. But how exactly does it come to the end result? What exactly is return returning during the recursive cases? It seems like it is just returning a call to a function that will continue to call the function until it returns 1 -- but it never seems to do any really calculations/operations. Contrast this with the classic factorial function:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
         return 1
    else:
         return n * factorial(n)
```

Here, the function is clearly operating on n, a defined integer, each time, whereas the fibonacci function only ever operates on the function itself until 1 is returned.

Finally, things get even weirder when we bring something like the Merge Sort algorithm into play; namely this chunk of code:

```
    middle = int(len(L)/2)
    left = sort(L[:middle], lt)
    right = sort(L[middle:], lt)
    print(left, right)
    return merge(left, right, lt)
```

left and right seem to be recursively calling sort, yet the print statements seem to indicate that merge is working on every recursive call. So is each recursive call somehow "saved" and then operated on when merge is finally invoked on the return? I'm confusing myself more and more by the second.... I feel like I'm on the verge of a strong understanding of recursion, but my understanding of what exactly return does for recursive calls is standing in my way.

Comment: Take a look at here:  http://cis.stvincent.edu/carlsond/swdesign/recur/recur.html  The examples are written in C++ but the recursion concept is explained pretty straightforward.

Comment: Python can be very misleading for people used to pure functional languages where recursion is a first class citizen; Python lacks tail recursion optimizations and there is a hard limit of ~1000 recursive calls. Most algorithms using recursion should be rewritten to use iterators in Python.

Comment: It should be `return n * factorial(n - 1)`, otherwise the `factorial` recursion never terminates.

Comment: @PauloScardine The OP is clearly not used to recursion in functional languages and running into the lack of tail recursion optimisation or the limited stack depth. The OP needs help understanding the concept of recursion, for which implementation details like tail recursion optimisation or stack depth limits are irrelevant.

Comment: @Ben: that's why it is a comment and not an answer; IMHO the comment is relevant for the OP and future readers because translating recursive calls to iterator based solutions is a good way to get insight about recursion while learning how to write safer and more pythonic code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not understanding how recursive functions work is quite common, but it really indicates that you just don't understand how functions and returning works, because recursive functions work **exactly** the same as ordinary functions.

```
print 4
```

This works because the `print` statement knows how to print values. It is given the value `4`, and prints it.

```
print 3 + 1
```

The `print` statement doesn't understand how to print `3 + 1`. `3 + 1` is not a value, it's an expression. Fortunately `print` doesn't need to know how to print an expression, because it never sees it. Python passes **values** to things, not expressions. So what Python does is *evaluate* the expression when the code is executed. In this case, that results in the value `4` being produced. Then the value `4` is given to the `print` statement, which happily prints it.

```
def f(x):
    return x + 1

print f(3)
```

This is very similar to the above. `f(3)` is an expression, not a value. `print` can't do anything with it. Python has to evaluate the expression to produce a value to give to print. It does that by going and looking up the name `f`, which fortunately finds the function object created by the `def` statement, and calling the function with the argument `3`.

This results the function's body being executed, with `x` bound to `3`. As in the case with `print`, the `return` statement can't do anything with the expression `x + 1`, so Python evaluates that expression to try to find a value. `x + 1` with `x` bound to `3` produces the value `4`, which is then returned.

Returning a value from a function makes the evaluation of the function-call expression become that value. So, back out in `print f(3)`, Python has successfully evaluated the expression `f(3)` to the value `4`. Which `print` can then print.

```
def f(x):
    return x + 2

def g(y):
    return f(y * 2)

print g(1)
```

Here again, `g(2)` is an expression not a value, so it needs to be evaluated. Evaluating `g(2)` leads us to `f(y * 2)` with `y` bound to `1`. `y * 2` isn't a value, so we can't call `f` on it; we'll have to evaluate that first, which produces the value `2`. We can then call `f` on `2`, which returns `x + 2` with `x` bound to `2`. `x + 2` evaluates to the value `4`, which is returned from `f` and becomes the value of the expression `f(y * 2)` inside `g`. This *finally* gives a value for `g` to return, so the expression `g(1)` is evaluated to the value `4`, which is then printed.

Note that when drilling down to evaluate `f(2)` Python still "remembered" that it was already in the middle of evaluating `g(1)`, and it comes back to the right place once it knows what `f(2)` evaluates to.

That's it. That's all there is. You don't need to understand anything special about recursive functions. `return` makes the expression that called this particular invocation of the function become the value that was given to `return`. The **immediate** expression, not some higher-level expression that called a function that called a function that called a function. The innermost one. It **doesn't matter** whether the intermediate function-calls happen to be to the same function as this one or not. There's no way for `return` to even know whether this function was invoked recursively or not, let alone behave differently in the two cases. `return` **always always always** returns its value to the *direct* caller of this function, whatever it is. It **never never never** "skips" any of those steps and returns the value to a caller further out (such as the outermost caller of a recursive function).

But to help you *see* that this works, lets trace through the evaluation of `fib(3)` in more detail.

```
fib(3):
    3 is not equal to 0 or equal to 1
    need to evaluate fib(3 - 1) + fib(3 - 2)
        3 - 1 is 2
        fib(2):
            2 is not equal to 0 or equal to 1
            need to evaluate fib(2 - 1) + fib(2 - 2)
                2 - 1 is 1
                fib(1):
                    1 is equal to 0 or equal to 1
                    return 1
                fib(1) is 1
                2 - 2  is 0
                fib(0):
                    0 is equal to 0 or equal to 1
                    return 1
                fib(0) is 1
            so fib(2 - 1) + fib(2 - 2) is 1 + 1
        fib(2) is 2
        3 - 2 is 1
        fib(1):
            1 is equal to 0 or equal to 1
            return 1
        fib(1) is 1
    so fib(3 - 1) + fib(3 - 2) is 2 + 1
fib(3) is 3
```

More succinctly, `fib(3)` returns `fib(2) + fib(1)`. `fib(1)` returns 1, but `fib(3)` returns that *plus* the result of `fib(2)`. `fib(2)` returns `fib(1) + fib(0)`; both of those return `1`, so adding them together gives `fib(2)` the result of `2`. Coming back to `fib(3)`, which was `fib(2) + fib(1)`, we're now in a position to say that that is `2 + 1` which is `3`.

The key point you were missing was that while `fib(0)` or `fib(1)` returns `1`, those `1`s form part of the expressions that higher level calls are adding up.

Answer (score 9):

Try this exercise:

What's the value of *fib(0)*?  What's the value of *fib(1)*?  Let's write those down.

```
fib(0) == 1
fib(1) == 1
```

We know this because these are "base cases": it matches the first case in the *fib* definition.

Ok, let's bump it up.  What's the value of *fib(2)*?  We can look at the definition of the function, and it's going to be:

```
fib(2) == fib(1) + fib(0)
```

We know what the value of *fib(1)* and *fib(0)* will be: both of those will do a little work, and then give us an answer.  So we know *fib(2)* will eventually give us a value.

Ok, bump it up.  What's the value of *fib(3)*?  We can look at the definition, and it's going to be:

```
fib(3) == fib(2) + fib(1)
```

and we already know that *fib(2)* and *fib(1)* will eventually compute numbers for us.  *fib(2)* will do a little more work than *fib(1)*, but they'll both eventually bottom out to give us numbers that we can add.

Go for small cases first, and see that when you bump up the size of the problem that the subproblems are things that we'll know how to handle.

If you've gone through a standard high-school math class, you will have seen something similar to this already: mathematicians use what's called "mathematical induction", which is the same idea as the recursion we programmers use as a tool.

Answer (score 4):

You need to understand **mathematical induction** to really grasp the concept. Once it is understood recursion is simply straightforward. Consider a simple function ,

```
     def fun(a):  
          if a == 0: return a
          else return a + 10
```

what does the return statement do here? It simply returns `a+10`. Why is this easy to understand? Of course, one reason is that it doesn't have recursion.;) Why is the return statement so easy to understand is that it has a and 10 available when it is called.

Now, consider a simple `sum of n numbers` program using recursion. Now, one important thing before coding a recursion is that you must understand how mathematically it is supposed to work. In the case of sum of `n` numbers we know that if `sum` of `n-1` numbers is known we could return that `sum + n`. Now what if do not know that `sum`. Well, we find sum of `n-2` terms and add `n-1` to it.

So, `sumofN(n) = n + sum(n-1)`.

Now, comes the terminating part. We know that this cant go on indefinitely. Because `sumofN(0) = 0`

so,

```
 sumofN(n) = 0, if n = 0,  
            n + sumofN(n-1) , otherwise
```

In code this would mean,

```
      def sumofN(n):  
          if n == 0: return 0  
          return n + sumofN(n-1)
```

Here suppose we call sumofN(10). It returns `10 + sumofN(9)`. We have `10` with us. What about the other term. It is the return value of some other function. So what we do is we wait till that function returns. Here, since the function being called is nothing but itself, it waits till sumofN(9) returns. And when we reach 9 + sumofN(8) it waits till sumofN(8) returns.

What actually happens is

> 10 + sumofN(9) ,  which is
> 10 + 9 + sumofN(8),  which is
> 10 + 9 + 8 + sumofN(7) .....

and finally when sumofN(0) returns we have,

> 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 0 = 55

This concept is all that is needed to understand recursion. :).
Now, what about mergesort?

```
   mergesort(someArray)  = { l = mergesort the left part of array,
                             r = mergesort the right part of the array,  
                             merge(l and r)  
                           }
```

Until the left part is available to be returned, it goes on calling mergesort on the "leftest" arrays. Once we have that, we find the right array which indeed finds the "leftest" array. Once we have a left and right we merge them.

One thing about recursion is that it is so damn easy once you look at it from the right perspective and that right perspective is called **mathematical induction**

Comment: This is an interesting explanation but it's not really induction.  It just happens to iterate backwards through the numbers.  I know it's similar here but the similarity disappears if you, say, write a recursive function to get sin(x).

Answer (score 0):

## Understanding the Internals of Recursion in Python

There are a few things that one must understand in order to grasp recursion in Python.

1. The 'stack' data structure
2. The properties of a 'stack'
3. What happens as the function is executing
4. How the function terminates

### 1. The 'stack':

A stack can be thought of as a list that only allows insertion, and deletion from one end, and one end only! I usually pick the left side to insert & delete from. So, if we have an empty list:

##### Pushing integers onto stack

```
push(1):       lst = [ ,  ,  ,  , 1]

push(2):       lst = [ ,  ,  ,  2,1] 

push(3):       lst = [ ,  , 3, 2, 1]

push(4):       lst = [ , 4, 3, 2, 1]  

push(5):       lst = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

##### Popping integers off the stack:

```
pop():           lst = [ , 4, 3, 2, 1] 

pop():           lst = [ ,  , 3, 2, 1]

pop():           lst = [ ,  ,  , 2, 1]

pop():           lst = [ ,  ,  ,  , 1] 

pop():           lst = [ ,  ,  ,  ,  ]
```

### 2. Properties of a 'Stack':

This a ‘stack’. It is what Python uses to hold function calls waiting to be executed. It uses the last-in-first-out or, LIFO method. Just think, ‘Pez Dispenser’, or how loading a bullet clip works. The other method of inserting and deleting that is NOT used on a ‘stack’ is the FIFO method. It is is used on the ‘queue’ data structure, which we won’t get into. Just think about waiting in a movie line, or a line at the store.

### 3 & 4. What Happens During Execution & Termination:

I always thing about recursion as a type of 'self-propelled' loop. Unlike a 'for' loop that uses the built-in 'next()' function to iterate to the next index in a list, or other data structure. The way that a recursive function iterates to the next value , or function call, is by calling itself with a decremented or incremented value of 'n', or with some other parameter. As we can see, our recursive function below is propelled by a series of self-references within the 'return' statement. The rest of the conditions are evaluated just as they are in any other vanilla loop. Therefore, The very first line of code that is run is the return statement.

```
def fib(n):
     
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
     
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
```

Above the 'return' statement, we have the most critical portion of code, the 'base-case'. Without the base case we would not have the ability to evaluate our series of function calls in total.

```
n = 5
push(fib(5)):       lst = [  ,  ,  ,  , fib(5) ]

n = 4
push(fib(4)):       lst = [  ,  ,  ,  fib(4), fib(5) ] 

n = 3
push(fib(3)):       lst = [  ,  , fib(3), fib(4), fib(5) ]

n = 2
push(fib(2)):       lst = [ fib(2), fib(3), fib(4), fib(5) ]  

###### base-case reached
n = 1
fib(1) = 1 

###### base-case reached
fib(0) = 0
```

Here is another way of looking at the call stack:
Fib(5) is composed of nothing but fib(4) & fib(3) right?

```
n = 5
push(fib(5)):   lst = [  ,  ,  ,  , fib(4)+fib(3) ]

n = 4
push(fib(4)):   lst = [  ,  ,  ,fib(3)+fib(2), fib(4)+fib(3) ] 

n = 3
push(fib(3)):   lst = [  ,  , fib(2)+fib(1), fib(3)+fib(2), fib(4)+fib(3) ]

n = 2
push(fib(3)):   lst = [ fib(1)+fib(0), fib(2)+fib(1), fib(3)+fib(2), 
                        fib(4)+fib(3) ]  

###### base-case reached
n = 1
fib(1) = 1 

###### base-case reached
fib(0) = 0
```

The base-case calls never get pushed onto the stack because Python already knows the value of fib(1) & fib(0). Python doesn't need to wait for them to be evaluated. That's what base-cases are. They are the keys for Python to be able to evaluate the rest of the function calls still waiting on the stack. We just need to reach the base-cases first. In the section below, imagine our stack entrance & exit is on line 4

```
 # order in which the calls are pushed onto 'stack'

                n      n-1      n-2
 1st call:  fib(5) = fib(4) + fib(3)
 2nd call:  fib(4) = fib(3) + fib(2)
 3rd call:  fib(3) = fib(2) + fib(1)
 4th call:  fib(2) =     1  +  0     <- base-cases reached, Python now 
                                knows the values of fib(2), fib(1), and 
                                fib(0). All function calls are evaluated on  
                                the stack then popped off and returned
```

### How Python evaluates with respect to the 'stack'

Since we reached our 'base-cases' Python now has the all the information it needs to evaluate all the function calls remaining on the stack. Imagine the entrance & exit is on line 1.

```
    fib(0) = 0 <-- base-case

    fib(1) = 1 <-- base-case




 1. fib(2) = 1 <-- popped off stack & returned

 2. fib(3) = 2 <-- popped off stack & returned

 3. fib(4) = 3 <-- popped off stack & returned

 4. fib(5) = 5 <-- popped off stack & returned
```